# Replace div contents using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to replace the image in the **featured-image class** with the image one clicks in the **thumbnail class**. I want to implement this using jquery ... I have been trying to use the ***$(selector).replaceWith()*** function but that doesnt work as expected. Below is my markup

```
<div class = "image-slider">
    <div id = "featured-image">
        <img src = "truck.jpg">
    </div>
    <ul class = "thumbnail">
        <li><img class = "small-image" src = "images/1.jpg" ></li>
        <li><img class = "small-image" src = "images/2.jpg" ></li>
        <li><img class = "small-image" src = "images/3.jpg" ></li>
        <li><img class = "small-image" src = "images/4.jpg" ></li>
        <li><img class = "small-image" src = "images/5.jpg" ></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Anyone with a solution that works without removing the clicked item from the unordered list? The solution should also allow one to switch the image multiple times. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.thumbnail img').on('click', function(e) {
    var _el = $(e.currentTarget);
    $('#featured-image img').attr('src', _el.attr('src'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(selector).html("html string here")`, or can pass a html node

Comment: how would you pass the html node in this instance to replace the image??

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this...
Replace src of image in featured-image class on clicking image from thumbnail class.

```
$('.thumbnail img').click(function(){
  var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
  $('#featured-image img').attr('src',imgSrc);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the attribute `src` with jquerys `.attr()` function.
Example: `$(selector).attr("src", "your image file");`

Here's a [reference](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also set an attribute to help you determine what image you would like to swap out to help make the jquery a bit more readable.

[Image Swap Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tpassolano/5rx1cm8f/)

```
<div class="image-slider">
   <div id="featured-image">
     <img src="//image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/147/147127.svg" height="250">
   </div>
   <ul class="thumbnail">
      <li><img class="vehicle" vehicletype="bus" src="//image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/147/147125.svg" height="50"></li>
      <li><img class="vehicle" vehicletype="ambulance" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/119/119083.svg" height="50"></li>
      <li><img class="vehicle" vehicletype="taxi" src="http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/147/147123.svg" height="50"></li>
  </ul>
</div>


 $(document).ready(function (){

    $(".vehicle").on('click', function(){  

        if($(this).attr("vehicletype") == "bus")
         {  
             $("#featured-image").html("<img src='//image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/147/147125.svg' height='250' />");
         }
         else if ($(this).attr("vehicletype") == "ambulance")
         { 
             $("#featured-image").html("<img src='http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/119/119083.svg' height='250' />");
          }
          else if ($(this).attr("vehicletype") == "taxi")
          { 
             $("#featured-image").html("<img src='http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/147/147123.svg' height='250' />");
          }
    }); 
});
```